# Jasper Reports wide crosstab on multiple pages

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, crosstab

I have a crosstab with many columns but only a few rows. When I generate the report the crosstab reuses the empty space below the rows from one page and renders the next columns for the same rows. This way several pages are compacted vertically on one page:
[image]

I want the columns from day **20** to day **27** (the second part of the crosstab) to be displayed on a new page not on the same page and leave that space empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to set the **[Column Break Offset](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/crosstabs/JRCrosstab.html#getColumnBreakOffset%28%29)** property of the crosstab to a very high value such that it exceeds the page height. This way the report will continue on the next page.

Comment: this happens with me also,but I want single table on single page,it(table) breaks into many pages by columns,I tried with Column  Break Offset=0 & =5 also,but no effect

Comment: @tiberiug Solved .. but can you describe brevity what is the meaning of this property `Column Break Offset`

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for hours. My only issue is that I'd like to print the remaining columns after the initials rather than printing all of the left-most columns, then printing the right-most columns that didn't fit. Is this possible?